# Milestone aspect ratio in pgfgantt adjusted for units?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt, units

So: I have a Gantt chart created with `pgfgantt` where in order to fit my pages I have included

```
x unit=1.4cm,y unit chart=6mm
```

in its preamble.  This means that milestone shapes are spread out horizontally.  How can I change the vertical and horizontal units of a Gantt chart in a way which doesn't affect the aspect ratios of elements like milestones?

Comment: You can always declare a new `milestone` element with an aspect ratio inverse to new `x unit` and `y unit` ratio. You must declare a new milestone because `pgfgantt` milestones doesn't consider aspect ratio as `diamond` original tikz shapes does.

Comment: Please consider to provide a minimum working example showing your problem? This way will be easier to help you.

Comment: Thank you - I can't however, find a way to set the aspect ratio of an element, nor of setting the width and height.

Comment: This is the reason because you must use a `newganttchartelement` as is explained in pgfgantt documentations

Comment: According to my documentation (v4.0), the relevant keys are left shift, right shift, top shift, height. But there is no width, or aspect ratio.

Comment: You're right there is no width or aspect ratio because `pgfgantt diamond` is a restricted version of `TiKZ diamond` shape. Therefore is not possible with actual `milestone` definition to change them. But you can create a new `milestone` element based on `TiKZ diamond` shape which includes `aspect`. Please, read pages 34 and 35 on v4.0 documentation.

Comment: @Ignasi care to write an answer? Or should it be closed as unclear (no MWE)?

Comment: @PaulGessler I'll try to write an answer, maybe negative, as soon as possible.

Comment: @PaulGessler After some tests I'm not able to provide an answer with an adjustable `newganttchartelement`.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly, then you can use `xscale` to adjust the aspect ratio. For example:

```
\begin{ganttchart}[
  x unit=1.4cm,
  y unit chart=6mm,
  milestone/.append style={xscale=0.42857} % 0.6/1.4 ≈ 0.42857
]{1}{12}
```

Comment: In my case, I find that xscale=y_unit/x_unit/2 works for me, where 2 is the default ratio between xunit and yunit.

Answer (score 1):

As [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/421955/263214) post was closed where I faced a similar issue, I am posting my solution here.

If your chart elements (e.g., milestone) are skewed due to the sizing of your chart (most probably due to the use of the `expand chart=\textwidth` key), and you prefer them to be equalateral, you can create a new chart element using the `\newganttchartelement*` macro (see Section [2.8](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf)).

For example, to define an equalateral diamond chart element, the new chart element's definition would be:

```tex
\newganttchartelement*{equalateralmilestone}{
  equalateralmilestone/.style={
    shape=diamond,
    draw,
    fill=black,
  },
  equalateralmilestone label font=\slshape,
  equalateralmilestone left shift=1.0,
  equalateralmilestone right shift=-1.0,
}
```

With the new chart item, you can now insert it into your Gantt Chart with the following layout below:

```tex
\begin{ganttchart}[expand chart=1.0\textwidth]{1}{10}
  \ganttbar{Task}{1}{7} \\
  \ganttequalateralmilestone{Milestone}{9}
\end{ganttchart}
```

which results in the following output:

[image: Gantt Chart with equalateral diamond shape]