# Milestone looks strange using pgfgantt

Tags: bar-chart, pgfgantt, gantt

As seen in the picture the milestone looks smashed up and strange, how can I fix this while still having the dates. I want to also have the dates there, as the regular one with all the dates takes to much room. I am open for other similar solutions for the chart.

```
\noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\ganttset{calendar week text= \small {\startday}}
\begin{ganttchart}[
hgrid,x unit=1.5mm,
hgrid style/.style={draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
vgrid={*{6}{draw=none},dotted},
time slot format=little-endian,
]{01.03.18}{20.06.18}
\gantttitlecalendar{ month=shortname,week=4} \\
\ganttmilestone{Forprosjekt}{03.03.18}\\
\ganttbar{Task A}{03.03.18}{03.05.18}\\
\ganttbar{Task A}{03.03.18}{03.05.18}
\end{ganttchart}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome. Try the method in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209252/milestone-aspect-ratio-in-pgfgantt-adjusted-for-units